# App Store and Ad Hoc disabled

Tags: iphone, ios6, app-store

When i try to create a App Store and Ad Hoc distribution option, its disabled in my apple account, where sometimes iOS App Development option also disabled.How to create a distribution certificate .Can any one please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You have reached to the limit of maximum number of "**Ad Hoc Distribution Certificates**" which is 3.  To create new one you must revoke an old one.

Comment: There is a limit? Didn't know that. What is the limit?

Comment: It is 3. Don't know why apple keeping this as a surprise to developers.

Comment: I only have 2 "Production" certificates shown in my certificate list but the option is still not available to me. Any other reasons why this can happen?

Comment: So I noticed. Thanks Aura

Comment: I'm on an enterprise account it it looks like its 2 for Inhouse & Ad-Hoc

Comment: So for any enterprise program only two people can build apps to distribute from their machine because they will have generated the necessary private key pair when creating the certificate. Can this private key be shared among machines then?

Comment: @Md1079 yes, you can export private keys from Keychain Access. Command-click on the private key and choose "export". You'll get a .p12 that can then be shared to other computers.

Comment: Just to clarify: does revoking a certificate used to publish an app in PRD, affects this app anyway?

Comment: @Ian MacDonald: Which private key is the relevant one to save ?

Comment: Is this limit is applicable for any time period? Or will I have to create a new account.

Comment: Any official link from apple website for this?

Answer (score 1):

For Development certificate the limit is 2 and for Production certificate the limit is 3

Comment: Any official link?

Comment: Nothing from Apple yet

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an individual `Ad Hoc Distribution Certificate` for each individual app you make. In other words, you can use the same `Ad Hoc Distribution Certificate` for multiple apps. The `Ad Hoc Distribution Certificates`, simply put, is a way for Apple to recognize and verify that your computer is a paid developer's computer.