# Xcode 6 GM provisioning profile for Ad-Hoc distribution

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios-provisioning

After install XCode 6 GM I CANNOT select the distribution provisioning profile for ad-hoc distribution.
The Xcode always uses "XC AD Hoc" profile.

I already tried by removing the profiles from the system (deleted all files in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`) and having Xcode to re-download the profiles from my Apple account but it didn't work. Reboot Xcode and system didn't help either.

Any solution to this matter?

Comment: you can see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774976/xcode-6-gm-creating-archive

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 you need to have a distribution certificate to generate an ad-hoc .ipa

So the steps you need to follow are, first create a distribution cert and then a ad hoc profile with this certificate and then the xcode will show the profile and you will be able to generate the .ipa