# Error in archiving Project in OSx Yosemite

Tags: ios, macos, xcode6, code-signing, osx-yosemite

I have recently upgraded my Mac to `Yosemite`. After that I tried to archive one of my projects. The archive was successful right before the upgrade. But after I have upgraded when I tried to archive(using the same setting and profile, nothing changed), I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
B42D4317C1A62AC9783161DC9FF31E76464470E8: no identity found
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I googled but didn't find anything helpful. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this fixed?
Xcode version 6.0. I am using Distribution profile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459911/resource-rules-has-been-deprecated-in-mac-os-x-10-10

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem for me. Can you please post this as an answer?

Comment: No problem just a link right

Answer (score 0):

Its a very common error for Yosemite now. the problem is that in Xcode 6, you can not create Archive using Developer Profile, you need to have distribution Profile to create Adhoc archive.

You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774976/xcode-6-gm-creating-archive)

If you already have Distribution Profile, just download it and double click on it, and then set the profiles in Xcode Code signing settings. If you still face any problem do let me know please.

Comment: I already said that the archive failed, I am using the distribution profile. You cannot upload application into app store using development profile, which I used to do before the upgrade.