# Detailed Explaination of IPA file and embedded.provisionprofile

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, provisioning-profile, ipa

Its very confusing and found lots of question answers on stack-overflow. But still there is not 100% perfect solution for developer. So I want to ask question about `.ipa` file and `embedded.provisionprofile` for detailed answer of provisioning profile + Certificates + Signing Identities.

(1) How to find out `.ipa` file is for development or distribution??
I have extracted ipa file and found `embedded.provisionprofile` with UDIDs and lots more detail. But There seems very minor difference between Development and Distribution app.

(2) How many types of Certificates/Profile available?
Here I am very confuse with ad hoc method. There are 3 options when I `archive` project and click on `distribute` button Bellow is image

[image]

1st option I know. It tells to upload app to app store simple enough. Second options is confusing, there are again two type (Please correct me if I am wrong) of development, like send it to your client/friend to test on his/her device and add to `TestFlight`(I am not aware of this) So what is difference here??. Also third one is simple says make archive file of xcode project but what is use of that archive file??

(3) How to make easyier to understand provision profile and certificates and signing identities and keychain access exporint and all that its very confusing and sometimes it gives misleading error. [Like this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438010/xcode-6-beta-2-issue-with-exporting-ipa-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di)

Answer (score 1):

first option is for uploading your app to AppStore

Second option:if you want to test your app in device so you have to go with this option, using this option you can generate **IPA** file. and this IPA will run only those device which devices UDID assigned to this IPA provisioning Profile

And i don't know about 3rd one.

Comment: For detail info you can join chat room and contact with me [IOS Developer Family](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family)