# 'Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution Certificate' when exporting for ad-hoc

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

When I try to export a project for ad-hoc distribution, I'm presented with the error message shown in the image. This project has been developed by another member of my organisation, on a different macbook to the one that I'm using at the moment. This original macbook is no longer available to obtain a developer profile from.

I've spent a good deal of time today working through Apple's documentation, and have tried (re)creating certificates, and revoking old ones - but with no success. This element of iOS development / roll out is new to me, so I'm very much stabbing in the dark at the moment.

I know there are some new elements to rolling an app out for Beta with Xcode 6; there are some good posts already floating around on here addressing some of those issues - but I'm utterly stumped trying to work existing answers in to my current problem. Any suggestions welcome.

[image: Xcode error message]

Answer (score 0):

> try resolving this issue by installing the **Xcode5.1.1**,

you can also refer the link

[xcode 6 beta 2 issue with exporting ipa "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438010/xcode-6-beta-2-issue-with-exporting-ipa-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di)