# Error in generating ipa file for testing

Tags: ios

I am using xcode6. 
I want to generate ipa file for testing purpose. When I archive the code and select *"Save for Ad-Hoc deployment"*, and then choose the account, xcode organiser gives an error:

> your Account already have valid ios  distribution certificate

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438010/xcode-6-beta-2-issue-with-exporting-ipa-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di

Answer (score 0):

I few days ago I was facing this same problem, tried to solve it, but the solution was dirty.

From Xcode 6 I archive the project. Then exit it.

Opened Xcode 5, go to Organizer and export Ad Hoc build with provisioning profile.

Couldn't do this with with Xcode 6. Hope this helps.. :)