# Error while uploading binary to app store

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode6, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload binary to app store but i got the below issue.

"Your account already has valid distribution certificate."

But i have valid distribution certificate. This is happening while uploading new app as well as uploading new version of old app. I tried with XCode 6.1 and 6.2 beta. I also tried with multiple machine. I don't know for which cases this error will be shown.

Comment: I got the same error what is given in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438010/xcode-6-beta-2-issue-with-exporting-ipa-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen when you have already generated a distribution certificate, and the distribution certificate that you have used to sign the application is different from the one that is present on Apple Developer Portal.

Try revoking the certificate in the Apple Developer Center, then go to XCode, Preferences, Select your Apple Id which has enrolled to the developer program, Click "View details", then Click on the "+" button and click on "iOS Distribution".

[image]
Then refresh the Provisioning profiles. Make sure you are connected to the internet.  I am hoping that this will fix the issue.