# Xcode 6.4 The Application You Have Selected Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit to iTunes Connect with Xcode 6.4. I am getting this error

> **Unable to Validate Your Application**
>   The application you have selected does not exist.

I am able to find the provisioning profile through my dev account on the previous step. I have double-checked all identifiers. I tried Application Loader as well and got basically the same error. What is weird is that I submitted another app several hours before to the same account with no issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is nice to know I am not the only one having this issue.   Was just fine the other day..   My app validates but can't submit...

Comment: Having the same problem. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277785/unable-to-validate-your-application-error-while-uploading-a-new-version-of-ios

Comment: guyz, is this issue limited to xcode 6.4, If i upgrade to xcode 7 would it allow me to upload, the Application Loader isn't working for me.

Comment: ***49 upvotes but none update the question text to show image is weird too***

Comment: My Radar on this got closed as a dupe: Engineering has determined that your bug report (23232727) is a duplicate of another issue (23215044) and will be closed.

Answer (score 32):

I tried Application Loader and it worked. It did not work 2 hours earlier. What is weird is that I tried to download an app from the App Store and they could not find my account. Some new terms of service popped up and I agreed. After that I was then able to download with the previous "non-existent" account. That's when I tried App Loader and it worked. Must be something on Apple's side that will be fixed shortly.

Comment: Is there somewhere from Apple to still download the Application Loader? Apple docs reference an old version of iTunesConnect.

Comment: Yeah. Go to your app in itunes connect. Create a new build (the next release of the app) and then go to the builds section. Once there, it says upload from Xcode 5.1 or higher or use application loader. Click on Application Loader and it will start the download.

Comment: Just tried Application Loader and it does work.  XCode, not so much.

Comment: I got the same error too, on 2 different apps! so... **It's probably another temporary problem at Apple's...** no app for you! come back - one day!

Comment: Exported the app for AppStore submission, and used Application Loader to upload the IPA file. Seemed to work fine!

Comment: I tried using Application Loader but It gave a bunch of other issues which dont make sense such as

ERROR ITMS-90049: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier contains disallowed characters. [See the section of the Application Programming Guide entitled The Application Bundle.]"
ERROR ITMS-90057: "Missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString."
ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion."

Comment: Application loader worked for me also. I guess its just an apple bug

Comment: worked!!! I don't think I've ever used Application Loader before but hey glad we have another route to iTC. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: From Apple about 1 hr ago: "I understand how important it is to get your app uploaded to our system. I want to let you know, we are aware of this issue. Our teams are actively working to resolve this as soon as possible. Your patience is appreciated during this time."

Comment: This worked for me as well, albeit on my second try with Application Loader. The first try, it got stuck on "Authenticating with the iTunes Store"...

Comment: I was facing issue with XCode6.4, the I tried uploading with Application loader and it worked, i got "The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message." but no errors and binary got uploaded.

Comment: @anoop4real Same story, same message, also worked for me too.

Comment: The Application Loader is embedded within Xcode: `Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app`.

Comment: Upload did work with Application loader but after upload we are having another issue. When app is ready for external testing. And we choose "Add build to test". After filling all required fields. Next button click doesn't work. It just reloads. Did anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Yes @Avinash I am seeing your issue. Was able to upload build using Application Loader, cannot submit build to beta review.

Answer (score 27):

I was having the same issue, here's what I did to send the app to the app store:

On XCODE create generate the "Archive", once you get the "Organizer" window/popup, validate it as you normally do. If validated, then click "Export" and select "Save for iOS app store deployment". Save it somewhere and take note of this location, you'll need the IPA file.

Install the "Application Loader" from https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg, if you don't have it already.

Follow the easy steps to push the app to the app store. That is "Deliver your app", select the IPA file and that's it!

Comment: Having same trouble with Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.1, but the Application Loader also worked for me. I got a warning about the API analysis being too large, but the build appeared on iTunes Connect.

Comment: One downside: the Application Loader doesn't upload the dSYM file that you need for crash reports... I use something else for crash reports but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: I could upload with Application Loader. But selecting both internal test and external text failed with strange error...

Comment: It isn't necessary to download Application Loader. Xcode comes packaged with it already. Navigate to "/Applications/Xcode.app" and right click the application icon. Click "Show Package Contents" in the menu. Now navigate to "Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app" Of course, it's just as easy to do this in the command line: `open "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app"`

Comment: The loader is available as a menu option in Xcode. Xcode >  Open Developer Tool > Application Loader

Comment: this works great. really frustrating as i hit the 2 issues in a row (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26061067/280970 the other one), and they are as vague at the best.

Answer (score 17):

While other are having success with Application Loader, I did not and received a different error **« You are not authorized to use this service »**  Great!

Since iOS 9.1 was just released yesterday perhaps Xcode 6.x is being phased out, but we're not ready to migrate to Xcode 7.x for this particular project.

I was successful by archiving in Xcode 6.x and using the Organizer in Xcode 7.1 to submit to the App Store.  The procedure is as follows:

1. Rename Xcode 6.x (In my case Xcode632.app).
2. Download and install Xcode 7.1 from .dmg file, **not as an upgrade**.
3. Build and archive your app in Xcode 6.x
4. Close Xcode 6.x
5. Launch Xcode 7.1 but **do not open** your project.
6. In Xcode 7 Select Window->Organizer.
7. Submit to App Store.

Hopefully this helps you if both the Xcode and Application Loader uploads fail.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the same errors as with every other method I've tried: [screen cap](http://i.imgur.com/DjV9IIj.png)

Comment: Based on your screen capture, you may be dealing with a compounded issue AWrightIV.  Check 3rd party SDKs in your project & related info.plist

Answer (score 2):

Download Xcode 7 and try to upload new build make sure that you changed version or (and) build number of app, it should work.

Comment: Using Xcode 7 does work but there are devs out there that don't want to mess with bitcode breaking things (like it did for me) and other networking changes. So Xcode 7 is a solution for some but not all.

Comment: @BeemerFan yea I just tried to upload new version using Xcode 6.4 and it did not work for me with the same issue, I updated my app 4 days ago and Xcode 6.4 works for me. But right now it works just using Xcode 7. Of course maybe someone knows how to make it work using Xcode 6.4

Comment: @BeemerFan, yea it can be a solution )

Comment: If you use Xcode 7, you will lose iOS 5.1.1 (iPad 1) support. That might not be a problem, but in my case I'm trying to get one last iPad 1 compatible release out before jumping to Xcode 7.

Comment: yea agree, but it's about 1% users, https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

of course if all your users uses 5.1.1 that can be a problem. But if it's already exist app and you have some analytic tool included you can see what are versions people use when download your app.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug/"feature" of iTC not related to Xcode version. Bundled frameworks should bump their versions(CFBundleShortVersionString) to match the version of the app.
Related topics:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4421
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/859

Comment: After trying for six days, this is the only solution that solved the problem for me. I recommend pasting the latest script from that link into your answer, however.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting and uploading via Application Loader worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Failed to upload archive using Xcode 6.4 and 7.1, but successfully uploaded with Xcode 7.0.1.
http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.0.1/Xcode_7.0.1.dmg

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It appears that Apple has remedied this bug. I just successfully uploaded a build using Xcode 6.4 to iTunes Connect. I believe this was either an organizer bug or an iTC bug but they've fixed it.

Before the solution was to use application loader.

You should be able to submit using Xcode 6.x now. We need to upload build from 6.x still because Xcode 7 requires a lot of refactoring due to ATS. The standard "AllowArbitraryLoads" doesn't cut it for my project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this can be caused by some new version number validation logic on Apple's end. In our case, tacking an extra ".1" onto the end of the version number strings for the app allowed it to be uploaded with Application Loader.

Really weird/deceptive that the error message for this would be "The application you have selected does not exist", though.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I tried to upload with Application loader then got descriptive errors about the bundle version. After removing all third party info.plist from pods and static libs, will work to upload my build.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I had to update my OSX to 10.10.5 and XCode to 7.0.1. In XCode you need to set few keys. NSAppTransportSecurity Key is required if your app or game needs internet access. After this setup it works perfectly from xcode it self. And no issue on live itunes connect.

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>domain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for similar problems is use of Fastlane Tools https://fastlane.tools
First You can use GYM tool for build/archive your project, and then Pilot for send it to iTunesConnect Testflight.
This tool fixes all of my problems with Code signing, submitting, etc. so I can recommend it.