# "Unable to Validate your Application Error" While Uploading a new version of iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

I have been trying to upload a new version for my ios App But I always end up receiving this error 
"UNABLE TO VALIDATE YOUR APPLICATION,
"The application you have selected does not exist"

From Xcode Archiver.
I followed this question here
[Xcode 6.4 The Application You Have Selected Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270301/xcode-6-4-the-application-you-have-selected-does-not-exist)

Which suggests to use Application Loader,
After doing that I ended up getting bunch of errors such as these

```
ERROR ITMS-90049: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier contains disallowed characters. [See the section of the Application Programming Guide entitled The Application Bundle.]"
ERROR ITMS-90057: "Missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString."
ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion."
The resulting API analysis file is too large.  We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery.  This is just an informational message.
```

This errors dont make any sense since all the missing keys are already present in my app, along with appropriate bundle ID of my app which has been in the Appstore for an Year now.

Can anybody help me out regarding this,

I seemed to have tried all the solutions I could find, but to no avail, anybody else facing this?
Is this another issue from apples server or maintenance side and I just have to wait a couple of hours before they fix it at thier end??

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? All frameworks should have the same version as your app.

Comment: I am using a bunch of frameworks, but they were all working yesterday when I uploaded it to testflight.

Comment: Yes and today Apple release iOS 9.1 and update there system. Go and check the Apple developers fora there are more issue with this.

Comment: so these issues are relevant to apple servers???not anything that I am doing?

Comment: Might be both, here is some script to set all the framework to the same bundle id version: https://gist.github.com/orta/29230398af6999136d8c Also see this technical note: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2420/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016603-CH1-WATCHKIT_APPS_AND_APPS_WITH_SUB_FRAMEWORKS

Comment: @Geet Where you able to fix this? I am facing it too..

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270301/xcode-6-4-the-application-you-have-selected-does-not-exist Seems like apple temporary problem

Comment: no..I have not been able to resolve it..

Comment: i am having same problem! was working for me yesterday too!

Comment: @VinoyAlexander and Andrew, were you people able to upload using Application Loader as all the others are saying, coz for me even that is not working

Comment: Just uploaded using App Loader as XCode is throwing error.

Comment: Having the same issue here! xcode 6.4

Comment: The answer which I have written below helped me, the issue was info.plist file of a third party libraray which i had used

Comment: I was facing issue with XCode6.4, the I tried uploading with Application loader and it worked, i too got "The resulting API analysis file is too large.  We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery.  This is just an informational message." but no errors.

Comment: @ anoop4real  I got this message too: "The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message."  What does it mean?  Do I need to fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: @anoop4real nope, it's just a msg... You can go forward and submit

Comment: @RRN it's  just an information message, I didn't do anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was facing the same issue but then i used **Application Loader** and it worked for me. After validating your app Export your app by selecting option as **Save for iOS App Store Deployment** and then Just upload your apps ipa using Application Loader.

Comment: What if the problem occurs during the validation process? Mine won't validate. I get error "archive is invalid" and "ipa does not exist"

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs how did you resolve your archive problem?  i have the same issue

Comment: Solved my problem.  After removing all embedded frameworks, rebuilding them, and re-archiving, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 19):

**Workaround Steps Using the Application Loader:**

1. Export your build as a file (Save for iOS App Store Deployment)
2. Go to Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader
3. In Application Loader log in to your account
4. Select and upload the .ipa file you just exported

Comment: Update: I've since updated to the latest Xcode version and uploaded a build just fine. Apple has no love for older versions of dev tools that they provide, nor those of us who still rely on them in one way or another.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue at Xcode 6.4. My workaround.

1. Rename Xcode 6.4 (Xcode64.app)
2. Install Xcode 7.1 (Xcode.app)
3. Build and archive in Xcode 6
4. Auto launch "Organizer" in Xcode 6 and **close**
5. Launch **Xcode 7 and Organizer**
6. Submit to App Store

Comment: Application Loader didn't work for me, got some message about "password is missing" and "u needs a value". This did work successfully with no problems.

Comment: Also a problem with Xcode 6.2. This method works as I already had 7.0 installed.

Answer (score 3):

I was with the same issue, Using the **Application Loader** works for me.

In Organizer, export your app and select the option  **Save for iOS App Store Deployment** I did it and works for me

before that I tried with **Save for Ad Hoc Deployment** but with no success!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was finally able to upload my application heres what  was happening, I had used a third party lib., which had an info.plist of its own

this info.plist was the culprit, It didn't had any `Bundle Identifier`, `CFBundleVersion` or `CFBundleShortVersionString` string, so I manually added These 3 keys into that frameworks info.plist and the application got accepted.

Dont know why but this worked, And I was able to upload my app to itunes

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with Xcode 6.4. Export the ipa and upload it using Application Loader.
Relevant [Apple Developer Forum Link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23672)

Answer (score 1):

This occurred for me when I accidentally left "Include Bitcode" checkmarked (on by default) in my build despite setting the project to not contain bitcode. Uncheckmarking it resolved this issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. So far despite this ref, we do not think we have iphone5 trouble, either. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/158809#158809