# Unable to validate your application and not uploading through Application Loader

Tags: application-loader

I'm trying to upload my build from Xcode6.4 but it gives "Unable to validate your application". Then I refer the [link from Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277785/unable-to-validate-your-application-error-while-uploading-a-new-version-of-ios) and trying to upload the app from Application Loader. But agin failure, application loader is not uploading the IPA. I'm getting following error 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To submit app to App Store use xcode 7.0 and above.

Please follow following steps if you are using xcode 6.4 & swift 1.2

1. You can archive using xcode 6.4
2. then open xcode 7.0 -> organizer submit using xcode 7.0

Thanks