# Xcode Error ITMS - 900490 "The bundle identifier contains disallowed characeters"

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

Didnt't work for Xcode 7.0. Updated to Xcode 7.1, still no go. My bundle identifier is com.xyz, no special characters in it. The question posted on StackOverflow similar to this one (ERROR ITMS-90049) has not be resolved. Any ideas?

Comment: Try [using Application Loader to submit, like the answer to this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33304480/981049).

Comment: Got the same issue "This bundle is invalid" with application loader.

Comment: Do you have any embedded frameworks, which have their own bundle IDs?

Comment: I'm using TMTumblrSDK, SDWebImage, and AFNetworking on Cocoapods. Then I have these libraries http://imgur.com/shHBrd2

Comment: Well, check the bundle IDs of all your embedded frameworks and bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It turns out that the framework "PlayAds.bundle" had an info.plist that had binary data and was corrupted. I removed the framework and it worked! It had nothing to do with my app's info.plist or bundle identifier.

Thanks everyone!