# Xcode 8.2.1 Unable to validate your application

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying upload my application which is in swift 3.0 to AppStore but I'm getting Unable to validate your application alert. [image]

and even I'm unable to generate ipa using Save for iOS App Store Deployment so as to upload using Application loader.

Can someone help me in resolving the issue

Comment: try this:- Check both while export ipa

1). Include app symbols for your application on Validate and upload to App Store. 2).Bitcode (un check).

Comment: Check the certificate and the Distribution profile which you are using to archive should be valid. Try to create a new provisioning profile and archive again.

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277785/unable-to-validate-your-application-error-while-uploading-a-new-version-of-ios

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Nativescript app (don't think the framework matters). I tried disabling bitcode (was already disabled), tried to just export the ipa to use it with Application Loader, but got `rsync failed` message.

The steps I did that removed this error was next:

1. In xcode account preferences I downloaded certs (I did that several times before so doubt this fixed it.. but wort a try)
2. Do Product>Clean
3. Bump app version from 0.9.1->0.9.2
4. Product>Archive successfully uploaded to iTunes

Hope solves the issue you have.
dp