# Xcode 7.2 archive validate failed

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store, archive

[validate failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPlBu.jpg)

When I archive my application,then validate for Mac App Store,but it failed like this,i do not know how to solve it, should I change Build Settings?
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QohR.jpg)

It archive success,but when i validate it,it show the error like this!

I use Xcode 7.2 in Mac OS X 10.11.3,i just think if there are some error setting in Build Settings?

Comment: Any screenshot? What error message you are getting?

Comment: Archive validation failed due to the issues listed below.

unable to validate your application.

The archive is invalid.

/var/folders/7m/vj5h7wzn067_705mjc0s4xjm0000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.gDn/

[yourApp].pkg does not exist.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270301/xcode-6-4-the-application-you-have-selected-does-not-exist

Comment: Which xcode version you using?

Comment: i use Xcode 7.2 in Mac OS X 10.11.3,i just think if there are some error setting in Build Settings?

Comment: Got exactly the same issue...